# Show $v\in FS_n$ is an $F$-multiple.

Tags: representation-theory

This is coming from Exercise 8 in Section 18.1 of Dummit and Foote.  We are talking about representation theory and in particular focusing on Example 3 and 10 in this section.

Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $G=S_n$ and $V$ be an n-dimensional vector space over $F$ with basis $e_1, e_2,...,e_n$.  Let $S_n$ act on $V$ by defining for all $\sigma\in S_n$ that $\sigma e_i=e_{\sigma (i)} $ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. So $\sigma$ acts by permuting the subscripts of the basis elements.  In the book they show that $V$ is an $FS_n$-module, where $FS_n$ is a group ring over $F$.

Our exercise says: Let $V$ be an $FS_n$-module.  Suppose $v\in V$ such that $\sigma  v = v$ for all $\sigma\in S_n$. We want to show that $v$ is an $F$-multiple of $e_1 +...+e_n$.

Now, I'm not completely sure what an $F$-multiple is, but I'm assuming that it means we want to show $v=\alpha (e_1+...+e_n)$ for $\alpha \in F$.

I've also just started working with representation theory so I don't really know what I'm doing, but here is what I have so far:

Suppose $v\in FS_n$ and $\sigma v=v$ for all $\sigma\in S_n$.  Let $v=\alpha _1e_1+...+\alpha _n e_n$.  We want to show that $\alpha _1=...=\alpha _n$.  Then we would have that $v$ is an $F$-multiple.  So far I have that since $\sigma v=v$ then $\sigma (\alpha _1e_1+...+\alpha _n e_n)=\alpha _1e_1+...+\alpha _n e_n$.  By definition of our action, we have that $\alpha _1e_{\sigma (1)}+...+\alpha _n e_{\sigma (n)}=\alpha _1e_1+...+\alpha _n e_n$.  Therefore, $\alpha _ie_{\sigma (i)} = \alpha _ie_i$ for all $i$. Hence, $e_{\sigma (i)} = e_i$ for all $i$.   So, $\sigma (i) = i$ for all $i$.  So, $\sigma $ is the identity permutation.

This gives us that $\sigma v=v$ implies $\sigma$ is the identity permutation.

This is all I have so far.  I don't know how this implies $\alpha _1=...=\alpha _n$.  This might not even be how we prove this, but this is all I could come up with.

Comment: Your assumption about what an $F$-multiple is is correct.

Comment: Okay, great.  Then at least I know what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: You somehow concluded that «$\sigma v=v$ implies that $\sigma$ is the identity», and that simply does not make sense! Why? Because you *assumed* at the begining that $\sigma v=v$ for all $\sigma$, so if what you did was correct you could conclude that all elements of $S_n$ are the identity, and that is not the case (provided that $n>1$)

Comment: You are almost there until you go in the wrong direction at the end. You have actually proved that if you pick $\sigma \in S_{n}$, then $e_{i}$ and $e_{\sigma(i)}$ appear with the same coefficient when $v$ is written as a linear combination of the $e_{i}'s.$ Since $S_{n}$ is transitive in $\{1,2,\ldots, n \}$, what can you conclude?

Comment: At some point you found that $\alpha _1e_{\sigma (1)}+...+\alpha _n e_{\sigma (n)}=\alpha _1e_1+...+\alpha _n e_n$, and deduced from this the equality of the first term on the left with the first term on the right, of the second term on the left with the second term on the right, and so on. If you reflect on this you'll see that it does not work. For example, $e_1+e_2=e_2+e_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\sigma v=v$ for all $\sigma$, and write $v=\alpha_1e_1+\dots+\alpha_ne_n$. As you said, it is enough to show that $\alpha_1=\dots=\alpha_n$.

If $\sigma=(1 2)$, then $\sigma v=\alpha_2e_1+\alpha_1e_2+\alpha_3e_3+\dots+\alpha_ne_n$, hence
$$ 0=\sigma v-v=(\alpha_2-\alpha_1)e_1+(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)e_2$$
and since $e_1$ and $e_2$ are linearly independent, this implies that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$. The same argument with $\sigma=(1\,j)$ shows that $\alpha_j=\alpha_1$ for all $j$.

Comment: Okay, this makes complete sense to me.  Only one question, $\sigma\in S_2$ and I need $\sigma \in S_n$, but does this work for $S_n$ because any permutation can be written as a product of transpositions?

Comment: Each transposition $(1\,j)$ is in $S_n$, it just fixes all the other elements.

Comment: Oh, right.  Okay, thank you so much. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is correct and strategy is good but perhaps you are overthinking the execution.

Let i and j be two arbitrary basis indices. Pick the symmetry $\sigma$ that interchanges $e_i$ and $e_j$ and leaves the other e's fixed. The equation $\sigma v=v$ just means that you can interchange the coefficients of $e_i$ and $e_j$ and you have two representations of $v$. But by uniqueness of representation in terms of the basis, this means $\alpha_i=\alpha_j$. So, the coefficients are all pairwise equal, hence mutually equal.